# iOS 7 UIKit NSTextContainer initWithSize:(CGSize)size conflict

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uikit, ios7, nstextcontainer

I have recently upgraded my xcode4.6 to 5.0 and I am facing conflict issues which I am not sure how to resolve.

I am using cocos2d library and CCGrid file in it is using UIKit framework.

Now UIKit function of NSTextContainer initWithSize:(CGSize)size is prompted as a conflict which causes error in CCGrid file of cocos2d.

Note : Cocos2d CCGrid used parameter of type ccGridSize till now,But Now prompted as a conflict.

Please suggest.